# Sql compress multiple similar subqueries into single subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql

Good day, my question is about optimizing sql query.
The following query is slow:

```
SELECT id, name,
, (SELECT rank_time FROM stage_rank WHERE stage = stage.id ORDER BY rank_time DESC LIMIT 1)::date AS rank_time
, (SELECT host_c    FROM stage_rank WHERE stage = stage.id ORDER BY rank_time DESC LIMIT 1) AS host_c
, (SELECT index_pa  FROM stage_rank WHERE stage = stage.id ORDER BY rank_time DESC LIMIT 1) AS index_pa
, (SELECT links_pa  FROM stage_rank WHERE stage = stage.id ORDER BY rank_time DESC LIMIT 1) AS links_pa
, (SELECT index_pb  FROM stage_rank WHERE stage = stage.id ORDER BY rank_time DESC LIMIT 1) AS index_pb
, (SELECT links_pb  FROM stage_rank WHERE stage = stage.id ORDER BY rank_time DESC LIMIT 1) AS links_pb
FROM stage
ORDER BY name;
```

I think it mostly because of repeated select from `stage_rank`, is it possible to make this select done once, and get all fields in single hit ?

Also any postgresql specific feaures might be of help here ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In `PostgreSQL`, you can select the whole record as a field and expand it later:

```
SELECT  id, name, (sr).*
FROM    (
        SELECT  id, name,
                (
                SELECT  stage_rank
                FROM    stage_rank
                WHERE   stage = stage.id
                ORDER BY
                        rank_time DESC
                LIMIT 1
                ) sr
        FROM    stage
        ) q
ORDER BY
        name
```

or rewrite the query:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT ON (s.name, s.id, sr.rank_time, sr.id)
        s.id, s.name, sr.*
FROM    stage s
JOIN    stage_rank sr
ON      sr.stage = s.id
ORDER BY
        s.name, s.id, sr.rank_time DESC, sr.id DESC
```

or rewrite it the other way:

```
SELECT  id, name, (sr).*
FROM    (
        SELECT  s.id, s.name, sr, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s.id ORDER BY sr.rank_time DESC, sr.id DESC) rn
        FROM    stage
        JOIN    stage_rank sr
        ON      sr.stage = s.id
        ) q
WHERE   rn = 1
ORDER BY
        name
```

Comment: @Girafik: means "expand the field `sr` (which is a record) into the constituting fields". Sorry, I forgot to add the alias, see the post update.

Comment: Please can you provide link to PostgresQL docs about selecting as record and expanding it, very grateful for this.

Comment: I know very little about PostgreSQL-specific features, but it seems to me you meant the innermost subquery in your first snippet to read `SELECT * …` instead of `SELECT stage_rank …`.

Comment: @AndriyM: no, I meant `SELECT stage_rank FROM stage_rank`. `stage_rank` here is a single field of type `stage_rank` (a record type reflecting the table type). This is the point.

Comment: I see, I misinterpreted the name. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: It is very sad, but rewriting my query as your first example given no positive result, ANALYZE telling absolutely the same query plan, postgresql is disappointing

Comment: @Dfr: please post the plans for both queries. Were the other queries faster?

Comment: Second query runs much slower, third i did not tried because my postgresql version is old(7.4) and it is not supporting those features.

Comment: @Dfr: out of curiosity: why don't you upgrade?

Comment: Sorry, i was mistaken with version. I have 8.4.2 installed. So third query runs about 3 times faster! Upgrading is difficult because there is already many databases running on that server and it is lot of work to upgrade it.